# How to get a PHP-Laravel homestead vagrant box up?

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I've set up a Virtualbox Ubuntu and installed Vagrant on it with

```
apt-get install vagrant
```

, nothing else.

According to this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead I've tried:

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

after this did not work I've used:

```
git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git ~/Homestead
```

and

```
bash init.sh
```

This seemed to work fine.
So I went into the folder where my code (and a Vagrant file) is and just tried

```
vagrant box add
```

(because I don't find a .box file or something like this... do I need one??)

Now I get the error:

> Message: LoadError: cannot load such file --
>   /media/sf_contractManager/project1/backend/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb

What am I doing wrong here?
As I understand Vagrant I should get a complete environment/vm out of the Vagrant box or? No need to install php, mysql, etc. inside the Vagrant box (or outside on Virtualbox level). 
Is this correct?
How can I bring the Vagrant box up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I went into the folder where my code (and
>   a vagrant file) is and just tryed
>
> ```
> vagrant box add
> ```
>
> (because I don't find a .box file or something like this... do I need
>   one??)

You don't need to do this, because you've already added a box on the previous step. Box is being handled on the Vagrant/VirtualBox level, not the your project level/Laravel level.

**Hierarchy**:

```
VirtualBox
|-Vagrant
  |-Vagrant box (environment for your project)
  | |-your project
  | |-another project
  |-another Vagrant box
    |-another project
```

To bring things up, you have to go to the folder where your `Homestead.yaml` is located and run `vagrant up`.

Remember to run `init.sh` before `vagrant up`.

> No need to install php, mysql, etc. inside the vagrant box (or outside
>   on virtualbox level). Is this correct?

[You are right](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead#included-software). But you have to specify all the "tools" you'll need to use with your project. For example, certain PHP/MySQL version.

---

For example, the fresh way to install (tested by myself on 18.04):

1. Install [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html) and [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) using the preferred way (`apt-get` or using an archive or something else). [How to install from `.deb` file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt). Just my opinion: get a source archive and isntall manually. This way you can control the version of the software you're installing. And you'll have some experience as well.
2. `cd ~` (go to Home directory)
3. `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`
4. `git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git ~/Homestead`
5. `cd ~/Homestead`
6. `git checkout release`
7. `bash init.sh` or `./init.sh`. Make sure that bash script executable. Or use

```
sudo chmod +x init.sh
```

to make it executable.

8. [Configure `Homestead.yaml` with providers you need](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead#configuring-homestead).
9. `vagrant up` (while being in Homestead directory).
10. If your project is a website, you might want to access it from your host machine. So you have to edit `/etc/hosts` file with `192.168.10.10  mywebiste.local` or so. You can find IP in the `homestead.yaml`.

You can find more info in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead#installation-and-setup).

Comment: Ah ok, I think then "git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git ~/Homestead" was not what I needed, because now I have two folders where I have a Homestead.yaml (the projectDir with the code from the repo and ~/Homestead) but when I try "vagrant up" in my project dir I get the same error "LoadError: cannot load such file...". How can I bring up the vagrant box in my project dir?

Comment: I recommend you remove all the stuff and start from the very beginning. Seems like you didn't follow all the steps from the docs. Maybe you missed with folders while running some commands or so.

Comment: if you're on linux you need to edit /etc/hosts as well

Comment: @Indra yep, if your PHP app is a website and you need an access from the host machine. Sometimes, for example, when you're working on CLI package, there is no need to add anything to `hosts`. So it's an optional step.

Comment: Tarasovych I wonder if you could take a look at my question about whether `vagrant box update` could have somehow dropped my MySQL databases? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60286908/470749